# Azure AD Access Reviews

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am wondering what the criteria are for Azure PIM Access Reviews recommendations?  In the documentation it gives an example of an interactive user not signing in for the last 30 days.  Do the PIM Access Reviews look at who hasn't activated their eligible role(s)?  Is there a corresponding report that could be pulled to view anyone who has not requested to elevate their privileges in the last x days?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Security alerts for azure ad PIM  if the user goes over specified number of days without activating the role. When an alert is triggered, it shows up on the Privileged Identity Management dashboard. Select the alert to see a report that lists the users or roles that triggered the alert. We have three levels of severity in security alerts.

**High**: Requires immediate action because of a policy violation.

**Medium**: Does not require immediate action but signals a potential policy violation.

**Low:** Does not require immediate action but suggests a preferable policy change.

We have a default rule called Administrators aren't using their privileged roles  you may configure this alert to get the list.

**Why do I get this alert?**

Users that have been assigned privileged roles they don't need increases the chance of an attack.

**Trigger:**    Triggered if a user goes over a specified number of days without activating a role.

**Number of days:** This setting specifies the maximum number of days, from 0 to 100, that a user can go without activating a role.

**Prevention**  Assign privileged roles only to users who have a business justification.Schedule regular access reviews to verify that users still need their access.

**How to fix?** Review the users in the list and remove them from privileged roles that they do not need.

[Security alerts for Azure AD roles in PIM - Azure AD | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/pim-how-to-configure-security-alerts)

You can also retrieve the group membership information and users who are activated by using power shell commands or scripts

Here are some references to use power shell commands

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/privileged-identity-management/powershell-for-azure-ad-roles

https://practical365.com/powershell-script-to-report-rbac-role-group-membership/